# How to map mylocal:2700 to mylocal:80?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, webserver, port

I want access my local Web-server *mylocal:80* through the *mylocal:2700* in browser. How can achieve it using small effort?  The thing is that i am using an external application api and the application requires *mylocal:2700* as its origin. we are working in several machine the local server of one of machine is *mylocal:2700*. I cannot change that one. So I am changing in all other machine. We are using apache and ubuntu.

Comment: Vote for closing because of Offtopic? Please comment why it became offtopic.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed. I feel the problem may be the title which is not a general question. I am not good at writing a good title. But reading the content anybody can update with a good title. It will be useful to others if you are  showing interest to make the title better than closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 27000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

Comment: Getting error "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name"

Comment: Not redirecting. Should I restart any service?